# Rails minitest - can I define all users except one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am new to minitest and I have tried searching for this but I can't seem to find an answer on this.

I am building some tests and I am looking at a scenario where I want to assert a test for any user EXCEPT a particular one.  In my case it's `:guest`.  For my example it's comments.  All users have to login, guests can't create or even read comments.

I am using the `policy-assertions` gem to test my Pundit policies.  I know I could build a test where I check that all users (nil) can create comments etc. then test that `:guest` can't but I figured there should be a way to skip the `:guest` user.

Comment: Kindly explain more. Weather you want to skip guest user from query results or you can to skip guest user during test execution?

Comment: I want a test that asserts all users except :guest can add a comment and that the :guest user can NOT add a comment.

Comment: You should write 2 tests for each CRUD case. i.e.
1. Login from normal user, create a comment, verify response(assert_response) and database(assert_difference).
2. Login from Guest user (or may be guest can't login), try to create a comment, response must be 404/403, also verify that there is no new entry in database.

Comment: Each user fixture has a authorization for commenting. :guest, :admin, :owner, etc. I can manually test for each user other than :guest. I am looking for a test that asserts that all users other than :guest can comment etc.

Comment: I believe this files tells how to test new and create for different type of users, https://github.com/ksimmons/codedorm/blob/master/test/policies/user_policy_test.rb#L16.
Notice some has assert_permit, while other has refute_permit